# How to persist files generated by a unit test?

Tags: c#, file, unit-testing

I have this simple method that writes some text to a file:

```
[TestMethod]
public void WriteTest()
{
    File.WriteAllText("text.txt","abcd");
}
```

Supposedly, it should be stored here:

```
TestResults\Deploy_Aybe 2017-10-08 16_33_11\Out\text.txt
```

However it's not ... when I debug the unit test I can see the file being created there, but as soon as the test ends, the file gets deleted.

**Question:**

How can I write to a file during a unit test and have the system not delete it ?

Comment: Create it somewhere else, instead of what seems a temporary output directory?

Comment: That makes sense !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm usually using Nunit, but my guess is that mstest cleans the shadow copy of your test after running. Your file is created in there.
You could use a specific path of your choosing.

```
File.WriteAllText("C:\bla.txt", "AllText");
```

That should keep the file from being cleaned up.

You can see I specified a path. In your case the file gets written in the active directory.
In my case to C